# List only Red Hat satellite child channel,per base channel

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing bash script to replicate channels from one satellite to another.

I want to get only the list of child channels for the base channel:
clone-rhel-x86_64-server.

I have intentionally used grep -E -A10 to give the option output of
up to 10 child channels.

Right now I am getting:

```
rhn-satellite-exporter --list-channels |grep -E -A10 '(^| )clone-rhel-x86_64-server( |$)'|grep  -v "^B"
C       child_channel1
C       child_channel2
C       child_channel3

C       child_channel4
C       child_channel5
C       child_channel7
```

My purpose is go get only the first section, i.e. only the child channels.

For base channel: clone-rhel-x86_64-server

```
rhn-satellite-exporter --list-channels |grep -E -A10 '(^| )clone-rhel-x86_64-server( |$)'|grep  -v "^B"
C       child_channel1
C       child_channel2
C       child_channel3
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is best suited for Unix & Linux SE!

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: While this question is suitable on Unix & Linux, it *is* a bash question, so it is on-topic here as well.

Comment: What distinguishes `child_channel{1,2,3}` from `child_channel{4,5,7}`? Is there something that makes them different from each other or is the blank line in between them the divider and you want ever channel above the blank line but not those below?

Comment: Hi Etan,you understood me correctly,child_channel{1,2,3} belongs to the required base channel,so I want to print the child channels above the blank line,and not those below the blank line

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use `perl`'s paragraph mode. From `man perlrun`:

```
   -0[octal/hexadecimal]
        specifies the input record separator ($/) as an octal or
        hexadecimal number. [. . .]
        The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph
        mode.  [. . .]
```

In paragraph mode, "lines" are defined by `\n\n` and not `\n` alone, so each "line" is actually a paragraph. You can therefore use a Perl one-liner and tell it to print the first line and exit:

```
rhn-satellite-exporter --list-channels |
    grep -E -A10 '(^| )clone-rhel-x86_64-server( |$)'| grep  -v "^B" |
        perl -00ne 'print;exit'
```

Note that the above will also print the empty line since that is considered part of the paragraph. To avoid that, you could either parse it out:

```
 rhn-satellite-exporter --list-channels |
    grep -E -A10 '(^| )clone-rhel-x86_64-server( |$)'| grep  -v "^B" |
        perl -00ne 'print;exit' | grep .
```

Or remove it in the Perl script itself:

```
 rhn-satellite-exporter --list-channels |
    grep -E -A10 '(^| )clone-rhel-x86_64-server( |$)'| grep  -v "^B" |
        perl -00ne 's/\n\s*\n/\n/;print;exit' | grep .
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,but actually I am getting the same results:rhn-satellite-exporter --list-channels |grep -E -A10 '(^| )clone-rhel-x86_64-server( |$)'|grep  -v "^B"|perl -00ne 'print;exit'
C       child_channel1
C       child_channel2
C       child_channel3

C       child_channel4
C       child_channel5
C       child_channel7   , I have  tried all the options..

Comment: @Max_il on what operating system?

Comment: Hi terdon ,the OS is : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6